# PGFPlots: point meta colormap index as fill value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I have the following simple PGFPlots sample

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
width=7.5cm,
colorbar,
colormap={mymap}{[1pt]
  rgb(0pt)=(0,0,0.5);
  rgb(22pt)=(0,0,1);
  rgb(25pt)=(0,0,1);
  rgb(68pt)=(0,0.86,1);
  rgb(70pt)=(0,0.9,0.967741935483871);
  rgb(75pt)=(0.0806451612903226,1,0.887096774193548);
  rgb(128pt)=(0.935483870967742,1,0.0322580645161291);
  rgb(130pt)=(0.967741935483871,0.962962962962963,0);
  rgb(132pt)=(1,0.925925925925926,0);
  rgb(178pt)=(1,0.0740740740740741,0);
  rgb(182pt)=(0.909090909090909,0,0);
  rgb(200pt)=(0.5,0,0)
},
point meta min=12.0628665990324,
point meta max=98.5559785610705,
colorbar style={
  ytick={20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90},
  yticklabels={20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90}
}
]

\path [draw=black, fill=blue, opacity=0.4]
(axis cs:0.722443382570222,0.322958913853178)--
(axis cs:0.361788655622314,0.228263230878956)--
(axis cs:0.293714046388829,0.630976123854488)--
cycle;

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and would like to fill the path with a value of the colormap, i.e., `point meta`. How to?

Answer (score 8):

This requires direct access to the colormap functions of `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
width=7.5cm,
colorbar,
colormap={mymap}{[1pt]
  rgb(0pt)=(0,0,0.5);
  rgb(22pt)=(0,0,1);
  rgb(25pt)=(0,0,1);
  rgb(68pt)=(0,0.86,1);
  rgb(70pt)=(0,0.9,0.967741935483871);
  rgb(75pt)=(0.0806451612903226,1,0.887096774193548);
  rgb(128pt)=(0.935483870967742,1,0.0322580645161291);
  rgb(130pt)=(0.967741935483871,0.962962962962963,0);
  rgb(132pt)=(1,0.925925925925926,0);
  rgb(178pt)=(1,0.0740740740740741,0);
  rgb(182pt)=(0.909090909090909,0,0);
  rgb(200pt)=(0.5,0,0)
},
point meta min=12.0628665990324,
point meta max=98.5559785610705,
colorbar style={
  ytick={20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90},
  yticklabels={20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90}
}
]

\path [
    /utils/exec={
        % map linearly from [0:1000] into the colormap. 500 is in the
        % middle:
        \pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{500}
    },
    draw=black, fill=mapped color]
(0,0)-- (0.5,0.2) -- (0,0.4) -- cycle;

\path [
    /utils/exec={
        \pgfplotsset{colormap access=direct}
        % direct access using an index. Yours has 201 elements:
        \pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{127}
    },
    draw=black, fill=mapped color]
(0.722443382570222,0.322958913853178)--
(0.361788655622314,0.228263230878956)--
(0.293714046388829,0.630976123854488)--
cycle;


\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since there is currently no key of sorts "use color map value", you have to resort to the macro which defines `mapped color` as outlined above. I used `/utils/exec`, a way of PGF which allows you to invoke a macro in a context where key-value pairs are expected.

Answer (score 5):

As with the release of PGFPlots v1.13 you can use the new keys `color of colormap` or `index of colormap` to get easy access to the colors of the colormap. See section 4.7.6 pages 192f in the manual.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0, xmax=1,
            ymin=0, ymax=1,
            width=7.5cm,
            colorbar,
            colormap={mymap}{[1pt]
                rgb(0pt)=(0,0,0.5);
                rgb(22pt)=(0,0,1);
                rgb(25pt)=(0,0,1);
                rgb(68pt)=(0,0.86,1);
                rgb(70pt)=(0,0.9,0.967741935483871);
                rgb(75pt)=(0.0806451612903226,1,0.887096774193548);
                rgb(128pt)=(0.935483870967742,1,0.0322580645161291);
                rgb(130pt)=(0.967741935483871,0.962962962962963,0);
                rgb(132pt)=(1,0.925925925925926,0);
                rgb(178pt)=(1,0.0740740740740741,0);
                rgb(182pt)=(0.909090909090909,0,0);
                rgb(200pt)=(0.5,0,0)
            },
            point meta min=12.0628665990324,
            point meta max=98.5559785610705,
            colorbar style={
                ytick={20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90},
                yticklabels={20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90},
            }
        ]

            \path [color of colormap=500,draw=.!80!black, fill=., opacity=0.4]
                (0,0)-- (0.5,0.2) -- (0,0.4) -- cycle;

            \path [index of colormap=128,draw=.!80!black, fill=., opacity=0.4]
                (0.722443382570222,0.322958913853178) --
                (0.361788655622314,0.228263230878956) --
                (0.293714046388829,0.630976123854488) --
                cycle;

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]