# TikZ style text color from colormap adds text to nodes (can't use e.g. `text=.!50!black`)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.style = {
    colormap name = viridis,
  },
}
\tikzset{
  cmapfill/.style = {
    color of colormap = {#1},
    draw = .!50!black,
    % text = .!50!black,
    fill = .!25!white,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[cmapfill = 200] (x) at (0, 0) {$x$};
\node[cmapfill = 700] (y) at (1, 0) {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works nicely, except that the text in the nodes has the color of the colormap, and I would like it to have the darker color `.!50!black` just like the border.

[image: Text color is too light]

If I uncomment the `text = .!50!black` line then the text indeed has the desired color, however the string `!50!black` appears in the labels too.

[image: Text appears in label]

How can I avoid changing the label text, but still change the text color?

Comment: `.` is not understood by TikZ but it uses it internally because that's what `xcolor` understands. It's not meant for end user.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, `#1` is not a color, it is the progress of the colormap. If I replace `.` with `#1` I get `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color '200'`.

Comment: @percusse, the `.` was suggested [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286837/2942). If it is not intended for users, what should I use instead?

Comment: @Ruud Oops, sorry. I'll delete my comment :)

Comment: @Ruud I said TikZ ;) not pgfplots. There is a different mechanism for `text` and path colors.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the color `.` into `temp` and then use `temp` in the mixes:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.style = {
    colormap name = viridis,
  },
}

\tikzset{
  cmapfill/.style = {
    color of colormap = {#1},
    /utils/exec={\colorlet{temp}{.}},
    draw = temp!50!black,
    text = temp!50!black,
    fill = temp!25!white,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[cmapfill = 200] (x) at (0, 0) {$x$};
\node[cmapfill = 700] (y) at (1, 0) {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice answer +1). however all explicit loading of `tikz` is superfluous. loading `pgfplots` is sufficient.

Comment: @Zarko I just copied that stuff from his MWE. Edited both.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question, but as a workaround, I generated a list of pre-defined colors using Matplotlib, which is where pgfplots got the colormap from in the first place:

```
from matplotlib import cm
cmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis')
for z in range(0, 51):
  print('\\definecolor{{viridis{}}}{{rgb}}{{{},{},{}}}'.format(z, *cmap(z * 0.02)))
```

This prints

```
\definecolor{viridis0}{rgb}{0.267004,0.004874,0.329415}
...
\definecolor{viridis50}{rgb}{0.993248,0.906157,0.143936}
```

After defining

```
\tikzset{
  viridis/.style = {
    text = viridis#1!75!black,
    draw = viridis#1!75!black,
    fill = viridis#1!25!white,
  },
}
```

It can then be used as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[viridis = 10] (x) at (0, 0) {$x$};
\node[viridis = 35] (y) at (1, 0) {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This works in TikZ without loading pgfplots at all.