# Tikz & Adobe Reader Rendering Problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, adobe, rendering

I generated a surface plot with Tikz and get some weird rendering when opening the document with Adobe Reader DC Version 2019.021.20058. Opening the document with Sumatra PDF works fine and the rendering is as expected. I think that it might have to do something with the opacity setting I made with `draw opacity = 0.25`. Maybe someone experienced the same issue already? This is the code I used (I removed the data table):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
%\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3.56in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.597in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=-5,
xmax=5,
tick align=outside,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={r [um]},
ymin=-0.1,
ymax=0.1,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={z [mm]},
zmin=-0.5,
zmax=0.5,
zlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
zlabel={F},
view={-37.5}{30},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
zmajorgrids
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
draw opacity=0.25, shader=flat corner, draw=black, z buffer=sort, colormap/viridis, mesh/rows=10]
table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
    %
    x   y   z   c\\
    -5  -0.1    -0.00401208789805135    -0.00401208789805135\\
    -5  -0.0777777777777778 0.0127129847757122  0.0127129847757122\\
    -5  -0.0555555555555556 0.036716779608439   0.036716779608439\\
    -5  -0.0333333333333333 0.0222293846011774  0.0222293846011774\\
    -5  -0.0111111111111111 0.00227144574341265 0.00227144574341265\\
    -5  0.0111111111111111  0.00254047801761024 0.00254047801761024\\
    -5  0.0333333333333333  0.0297936697032036  0.0297936697032036\\
    -5  0.0555555555555556  0.0641190035549535  0.0641190035549535\\
    -5  0.0777777777777778  0.0426240518586565  0.0426240518586565\\
    -5  0.1 0.0169087899832898  0.0169087899832898\\
    -3.88888888888889   -0.1    -0.015484363255738  -0.015484363255738\\
    -3.88888888888889   -0.0777777777777778 -0.00658364063490503    -0.00658364063490503\\
    -3.88888888888889   -0.0555555555555556 0.0374001829941534  0.0374001829941534\\
    -3.88888888888889   -0.0333333333333333 0.0903030127730051  0.0903030127730051\\
    -3.88888888888889   -0.0111111111111111 0.0495343034499379  0.0495343034499379\\
    -3.88888888888889   0.0111111111111111  0.0549014851826079  0.0549014851826079\\
    -3.88888888888889   0.0333333333333333  0.124351706765753   0.124351706765753\\
    -3.88888888888889   0.0555555555555556  0.0831130685984939  0.0831130685984939\\
    -3.88888888888889   0.0777777777777778  0.0236508342699349  0.0236508342699349\\
    -3.88888888888889   0.1 0.000772669611202617    0.000772669611202617\\
    -2.77777777777778   -0.1    -0.0241049941831575 -0.0241049941831575\\
    -2.77777777777778   -0.0777777777777778 -0.0347501170423212 -0.0347501170423212\\
    -2.77777777777778   -0.0555555555555556 -0.02146866231587   -0.02146866231587\\
    -2.77777777777778   -0.0333333333333333 0.104912371785295   0.104912371785295\\
    -2.77777777777778   -0.0111111111111111 0.271765229303948   0.271765229303948\\
    -2.77777777777778   0.0111111111111111  0.303958209301988   0.303958209301988\\
    -2.77777777777778   0.0333333333333333  0.172958471019881   0.172958471019881\\
    -2.77777777777778   0.0555555555555556  0.0220124534128152  0.0220124534128152\\
    -2.77777777777778   0.0777777777777778  -0.0150031457580592 -0.0150031457580592\\
    -2.77777777777778   0.1 -0.0153890857895004 -0.0153890857895004\\
    -1.66666666666667   -0.1    -0.0226741697539306 -0.0226741697539306\\
    -1.66666666666667   -0.0777777777777778 -0.0460320661669208 -0.0460320661669208\\
    -1.66666666666667   -0.0555555555555556 -0.0935816857307185 -0.0935816857307185\\
    -1.66666666666667   -0.0333333333333333 -0.135176806679241  -0.135176806679241\\
    -1.66666666666667   -0.0111111111111111 0.0399685807772132  0.0399685807772132\\
    -1.66666666666667   0.0111111111111111  0.086570250864977   0.086570250864977\\
    -1.66666666666667   0.0333333333333333  -0.0874842686079726 -0.0874842686079726\\
    -1.66666666666667   0.0555555555555556  -0.0750257955087438 -0.0750257955087438\\
    -1.66666666666667   0.0777777777777778  -0.0394801296332671 -0.0394801296332671\\
    -1.66666666666667   0.1 -0.0201403091797877 -0.0201403091797877\\
    -0.555555555555556  -0.1    -0.00934184338403441    -0.00934184338403441\\
    -0.555555555555556  -0.0777777777777778 -0.0217060664441407 -0.0217060664441407\\
    -0.555555555555556  -0.0555555555555556 -0.0588447174552641 -0.0588447174552641\\
    -0.555555555555556  -0.0333333333333333 -0.180702173698492  -0.180702173698492\\
    -0.555555555555556  -0.0111111111111111 -0.457167073238262  -0.457167073238262\\
    -0.555555555555556  0.0111111111111111  -0.449792069295717  -0.449792069295717\\
    -0.555555555555556  0.0333333333333333  -0.175604141233837  -0.175604141233837\\
    -0.555555555555556  0.0555555555555556  -0.0573261872305043 -0.0573261872305043\\
    -0.555555555555556  0.0777777777777778  -0.0212374986770804 -0.0212374986770804\\
    -0.555555555555556  0.1 -0.0091729747305676 -0.0091729747305676\\
    0.555555555555556   -0.1    0.00935266817522145 0.00935266817522145\\
    0.555555555555556   -0.0777777777777778 0.0217315306196318  0.0217315306196318\\
    0.555555555555556   -0.0555555555555556 0.058916064174099   0.058916064174099\\
    0.555555555555556   -0.0333333333333333 0.18094221535962    0.18094221535962\\
    0.555555555555556   -0.0111111111111111 0.457897535370235   0.457897535370235\\
    0.555555555555556   0.0111111111111111  0.450583886312023   0.450583886312023\\
    0.555555555555556   0.0333333333333333  0.17588713521802    0.17588713521802\\
    0.555555555555556   0.0555555555555556  0.0574104229738243  0.0574104229738243\\
    0.555555555555556   0.0777777777777778  0.0212669447798271  0.0212669447798271\\
    0.555555555555556   0.1 0.00918524565909952 0.00918524565909952\\
    1.66666666666667    -0.1    0.0227591779657269  0.0227591779657269\\
    1.66666666666667    -0.0777777777777778 0.0462215857761375  0.0462215857761375\\
    1.66666666666667    -0.0555555555555556 0.09406029260016    0.09406029260016\\
    1.66666666666667    -0.0333333333333333 0.136455316943904   0.136455316943904\\
    1.66666666666667    -0.0111111111111111 -0.0374742884697211 -0.0374742884697211\\
    1.66666666666667    0.0111111111111111  -0.0841628989286638 -0.0841628989286638\\
    1.66666666666667    0.0333333333333333  0.0888197684680089  0.0888197684680089\\
    1.66666666666667    0.0555555555555556  0.0755607478627433  0.0755607478627433\\
    1.66666666666667    0.0777777777777778  0.0396950890798034  0.0396950890798034\\
    1.66666666666667    0.1 0.0202363055482996  0.0202363055482996\\
    2.77777777777778    -0.1    0.0242977879266081  0.0242977879266081\\
    2.77777777777778    -0.0777777777777778 0.0351362663175424  0.0351362663175424\\
    2.77777777777778    -0.0555555555555556 0.0222556916932093  0.0222556916932093\\
    2.77777777777778    -0.0333333333333333 -0.103606517646555  -0.103606517646555\\
    2.77777777777778    -0.0111111111111111 -0.270720623003105  -0.270720623003105\\
    2.77777777777778    0.0111111111111111  -0.303198917832974  -0.303198917832974\\
    2.77777777777778    0.0333333333333333  -0.171928109399461  -0.171928109399461\\
    2.77777777777778    0.0555555555555556  -0.0212564580476906 -0.0212564580476906\\
    2.77777777777778    0.0777777777777778  0.0154073095258305  0.0154073095258305\\
    2.77777777777778    0.1 0.015597141507947   0.015597141507947\\
    3.88888888888889    -0.1    0.0157628574375591  0.0157628574375591\\
    3.88888888888889    -0.0777777777777778 0.00705615322725028 0.00705615322725028\\
    3.88888888888889    -0.0555555555555556 -0.0367110580709496 -0.0367110580709496\\
    3.88888888888889    -0.0333333333333333 -0.0897543809034257 -0.0897543809034257\\
    3.88888888888889    -0.0111111111111111 -0.0494153064194497 -0.0494153064194497\\
    3.88888888888889    0.0111111111111111  -0.0548506571675378 -0.0548506571675378\\
    3.88888888888889    0.0333333333333333  -0.124063304347714  -0.124063304347714\\
    3.88888888888889    0.0555555555555556  -0.0825751983589331 -0.0825751983589331\\
    3.88888888888889    0.0777777777777778  -0.0232092007484423 -0.0232092007484423\\
    3.88888888888889    0.1 -0.000491322877996847   -0.000491322877996847\\
    5   -0.1    0.00431672091395933 0.00431672091395933\\
    5   -0.0777777777777778 -0.0123023008615549 -0.0123023008615549\\
    5   -0.0555555555555556 -0.0363400046928452 -0.0363400046928452\\
    5   -0.0333333333333333 -0.0221189632783751 -0.0221189632783751\\
    5   -0.0111111111111111 -0.00226706308941551    -0.00226706308941551\\
    5   0.0111111111111111  -0.0025399919020506 -0.0025399919020506\\
    5   0.0333333333333333  -0.0297604060011352 -0.0297604060011352\\
    5   0.0555555555555556  -0.0638885287072771 -0.0638885287072771\\
    5   0.0777777777777778  -0.0422884175360415 -0.0422884175360415\\
    5   0.1 -0.0166249395977068 -0.0166249395977068\\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I updated the code. I was able to compile this file. I have also attached two images of my Sumatra PDF View and the Adobe Acrobat DC view.

This is the Sumatra PDF View:
[image]

This is the Adobe Reader View:
[image]

Comment: Your MWE does not compile for me, please provide some mock data, e.g. with `filecontents`.

Comment: I added some data to the code. This code should compile now

Comment: Please make it a full minimal example. There is no preamble of document class

Comment: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}` works for me, but. I see no transparency in neither Preview 10.1 nor in Adobe Acrobat 9.

Comment: I confirm @OlegLobachev's observation and would like, too, to urge you to provide a full yet minimal document that has the issue. In your document there might be some settings with, say, `blend mode`, which we do not see. BTW, you could also add `fill opacity=1` and see if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I updated the post and also tried to set `fill opacity = 1` but it did not change anything.

Comment: I looked again at the renderings from the latest version in both Acrobat and Preview _at very large magnifications_. They indeed look a bit differently, but some transparency in lines (and only in lines, not in the surfaces) is there.

Comment: Thank you for having a look! It gets problematic if the samples are much higher. You basically cannot get the information out of the plot anymore. Where does the difference come from between Sumatra and Adobe. Sumatra renders it as expected.

Comment: I found a post where opacity settings were adressed and `\pdfpageattr{/Group <</S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}` fixed the problem. This does not work for this problem.

Comment: The problem is, that at high sample rates the transparent lines dominate and make the whole plot looking more transparent. This only occurs in Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my rendering issue by setting the draw color as proposed in the following post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277604/193105

I have set the properties to `draw=mapped color!75!black,draw opacity = 1, text opacity=1, fill opacity=1`. This does not solve the issue with the opacity rendering problem but gives nearly the same result compared to setting `draw opacity=25` since the colors used to draw the line close to the resulting color for a black color with opacity.